# Why Bala Parameswari not included in Dasamahavidyas

Tags: shaktism

As far as i know,  SriVidya krama has included Bala mantra upasana.

But, why DasaMahavidyas doesn't include mentioning of Bala Parameswari.Though, it has Tripurasundari, Bhuvaneswari, TarA etc..
, but BAala seems to be missing !!!&& there is big difference between Bala Tripurasundari ( TryAkshAri)
&& TripurAsundAri( Shodashi/ PanchaDasi).

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Because she is manifestation of Sri Lalita. So it is not added as a separate mahavidya. She is the initial step of sri vidya upasana.

Comment: mantras may be different. but if you check lalita upakhyana you will find connection between both

Comment: There are three kinds of Tripura devis .. and  Bala Tripurasundari is one of them .. and Tripura devis are supreme Goddesses so she is also one.. There are many Mahavidyas but she isn't counted among the 10

Comment: What are three kinds??,  i think its two.  Bala- 9 yrs old   && Lalitha - mother goddess. May i know the third...

Comment: @SaMolPP Tripurasundari, Tripurabhairavi and Bala .. they are all Tripuras and hence they are supreme Goddesses

Comment: Ohh okay!! I missed Tripurabhairavi... Dhanyosmi...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can not answer such questions. With matters like this scriptures are our sole guide. So, we can not ask why a particular deity is not there in the Dashamahavidya list.

The lists found in scriptures do not include  Bala Tripurasunadri that's why she isn't included. This will be the only answer.

Brihaddharma Purana, Madyabhaga gives the usual list:

> MahAvidyA imAh proktA nAmAnyAsantu varnaye |
>   KAli tArA mahAvidyA
>   shodashi bhuvaneswari ||
>   BhairvaichinnamstA cha sundari
>   bagalamukhi|
>   dhumAvati cha mAtangi mahAvidyA dashaiva TAh ||
>
> *Brihaddharma PurAna, MadhyabhAga.*

This list gives the names of KAli, TArA, Shodashi, Bhuvaneswari etc but does not include BAlA.

The MundamAlA Tantram gives the same names and does not include BAlA too.

> KAli tArA mahAvidyA shodashi bhuvaneswari |
>    Bhairavi
>   chinnamstA cha vidyA dhumAvati tathA ||
>    BagalAmukhi siddhavidyA
>   mAtangi kamalAtmikA |
>    EtA dasha mahAvidyA siddhavidyA
>   prakirtitAh ||
>
> *MundamAlA Tantram.*

But still BAlA is a Supreme Goddess because she is one of the three Tripura Devis.

Lord Shiva says:

> TripurA trividhA devi bAlA proktA purA shive |
>  Tathaiva bhairavi
>   devi nityA-tantre mayoditA ||
>  IdAnim sundarim devim srinu pArvati
>   sadaram ||
>
> Tripura Devis are of three types; Among whom I have already said about
>   BAlA and Tripura Bhairavi in NityA-Tantram previously. Now, listen O
>   PArvati with due respect about Tripura Sundari.
>
> *Sri MAtrikA bheda Tantram 7.1,2*

One meaning of Tripura is the Devi who existed before the Trinities who are in turn the Supreme deities of Hinduism.

Therefore, she is a Supreme Goddess even though she is not included among the ten MahAvidyAs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different kaula tantric traditions one is srividya (lalita & 16 nityas) and other is kalividya (kali  & 10 mahavidyas).Bala paramesvari belongs to the former.

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate bit more with citing some sources.

Comment: No tantric is allowed to publish their knowledge to anyone ,no matter who is it.As being a followerni can't give anyone all the details.I can only give hint to you.You have to find the path yourself.

Comment: Oh! ok. Btw, this [meta discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/426/277) is related.